# How to set the hostname with a script at boot for Debian Jessie?

Tags: debian, systemd

I have a Debian Jessie installation that I boot with PXE and I need to set the hostname at boot using a script.

I used /etc/init.d/hostname.sh with the previous Debian version, but it doesn't seems to be executed at boot. Maybe because of systemd.

Answer (score 1):

Check you gave execution right to your script

```
#chmod +x hostname.sh
```

Why don't you use the DHCP option 12 instead?

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1533

```
3.14. Host Name Option
   This option specifies the name of the client.  The name may or may
   not be qualified with the local domain name (see section 3.17 for the
   preferred way to retrieve the domain name).  See RFC 1035 for
   character set restrictions.

   The code for this option is 12, and its minimum length is 1.

    Code   Len                 Host Name
   +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+--
   |  12 |  n  |  h1 |  h2 |  h3 |  h4 |  h5 |  h6 |  ...
   +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+--
```

Edit_1

you can also add the deb-conf variable "hostname" as a kernel parameter in the "append" line i.e.

```
 append  initrd=xxx/www/zzz.img  hostname=myhostname ....
```

Comment: hostname.sh is from Debian. It's not mine.

I wish I could use DHCP option 12 but I think we can't since we have a crappy DHCP server.

Comment: see the edited answer